# Ubuntu 16.04 VPS phppgadmin 404 not found

Tags: server, postgresql, phppgadmin

I'm trying to set up phppgadmin on my virtual private server so that I can access it remotely. I've followed all of the steps in this [tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-postgresql-installation/), but when I go to http://localhost/phppgadmin, I get a "404 Not Found" error. Can anyone help me? I'm not sure what the solution is

Comment: Did you double check your conf file? Sometimes when configuring in vi alot of times it comes down to "Oops, forgot to save".

Comment: I just double checked it. I commented out "Require local" and put "Allow From all". I also set the extra login security to "false" like the tutorial specified.

Comment: Did you try with http://[Your IP. e.g 127.0.0.1]/phppgadmin? Or check ipconfig (ifconfig in linux)?

Comment: I did http://[IP OF SERVER]/phppgadmin and it gives me a 404 error. I have not checked ipconfig

Edit: Just checked using ifconfig in windows. I'm seeing the same IP that I've been using

Comment: Check this, seems similar (possible duplicate) https://askubuntu.com/questions/451378/phppgadmin-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I saw that earlier...I don't think it applies the conf.d directory doesn't exist for me. Thanks for the help though...I'm at a loss for what to do. Might just try another web-based tool besides phppgadmin